# select multiple mysql columns in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

In a joomla program I made I request two columns from a database table using the following code:

```
    $db=JFactory::getDbo();

    $query=$db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('keywords','en_GB_tips')))
    ->from('#__tooltip_explain');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $keywords=$db->loadColumn(0);
    $tips=$db->loadColumn(1);
```

This code used to work but recently the last command : loadColumn(1) comes back empty. I tried multiple versions but basicly if I request more than 1 column/row only the first one contains data. My server is an apache2 instance running the latest php and mysql 5.6. I also tried on another server also running apache2 but with mariadb as a database and it doesn't work there either. I does however run on an old server with mysql 5.5.

Does anybody have any idea why this works with mysql 5.5 and not another database? (I do not own the server with mysql 5.6 so I can't be sure if it was updated recently from 5.5 to 5.6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('keywords','en_GB_tips')))
      ->from('#__tooltip_explain');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results  = $db->loadObject();//if more than one row then loadObjectList()
$keywords = $results->keywords;
$tips     = $results->en_GB_tips;
```

Joomla Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

Comment: I can use this for a workaround (but then loadAssocList($key,$column) would be better). However this does not give an array with the values from the requested columns but a row in a 2D array. The big question is what happend to my server that the loadColumn command no longer works